# 1/3 screen, full screen background with responsive scaling

Tags: html, css, image, media-queries

I am making my home page have a large image (just a static image for now, maybe a slideshow or something later) and I have the height set at 60%, width 100%. Set as a background image in css (seperate style sheet)

It is a detailed image that takes up full width, takes up the entire space.

I want the image to scale and fill the entire height/width of the 60% max-height 100% min-width as the screen resizes (responsive, 40% height when mobile). I don't want any cropping as it resizes. (at worst, just crop the top, the main focus is that the sides remain un-cropped)

I tried background-size: cover - it crops a lot when portrait and other weird sizes (especially mobile and portrait)

I tried background-size: contain - doesn't fill the space properly when resized.

basically all the "full screen background" tutorials don't work since it's only around 1/2 screen at most.

- cross browser support importent as well

Hope I explained it well enough,  any help is greatly appreciated

- Cheers

Comment: What's your CSS/HTML? Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: current css:  background: url(../images/temp_header.jpg) center bottom no-repeat;
   height: 60%;
   min-width: 100%;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;

Comment: could your provide any fiddle?

Comment: never used it, I'm more a designer than a coder. Basically I'm just trying to keep the sides of the image visible and on the sides of the screen as it scales horizontally. 'background-size: cover' would work great if it didn't crop the sides when scaled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use media queries for smaller screens. Because you want to limit the background by height and yet maintain aspect ratio, you will have to use a hack by applying a background to a pseudo-element.

***Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/nxydcu70/2/***

***Example Snippet***: (View full screen and resize to see)

```css
html, body { 
    box-sizing: border-box; margin:0; padding:0; 
    width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; 
}
body { color: #fff; text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #333; }
body::before {
    content: ''; transition: all 500ms; 
    position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; height: 70%;
    z-index: -10;
    background-origin: border-box;
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/1000/600") bottom center / cover no-repeat transparent; 
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    body::before {
        content: ''; transition: all 500ms; 
        position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; height: 40%;
        z-index: -10;
        background-origin: border-box;
        background: url("http://lorempixel.com/1000/600") center center / cover no-repeat transparent; 
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Responsive background limited by height</h1>
```

---

### Update:

If you want to use it only on header and not the body, then no need to use the pseudo-elements. Just make the header height to 60%.

***Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/pmtr5707/2/***

***Updated Snippet***:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin:0; padding:0; }
html, body { 
    width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; 
}
header {
    width: 100%; height: 60%;
    background-origin: border-box;
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/1000/600") bottom center / cover no-repeat transparent; 
    transition: all 500ms; 
}
header > h1 { color: #fff; text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #333; }
header, section, footer { padding: 15px; }
footer { border-top: 1px solid #eee; }

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    header {
        width: 100%; height: 40%;
        background-origin: border-box;
        background: url("http://lorempixel.com/1000/600") center center / cover no-repeat transparent; 
        transition: all 500ms; 
    }
}
```

```html
<header><h1>Header</h1></header>
<section><p>Content</p></section>
<footer><h2>Footer</h2></footer>
```

Comment: That's closer, and fixes the width issue fairly well. Is it possible to not crop the bottom and top (crop just the top if it has to). And does it have to use the body tag/html tag?

Comment: Just make the position as `bottom center` so that it aligns at the bottom and crops away at the top, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/nxydcu70/2/ Background has to be applied to the pseudo-element ***of*** the element on which you want a background. So, if you want a background on `body`, apply it to `body::before`. If you want on a `div`, then apply it on `div::before`

Comment: Then apply it on that `div`.

Comment: do i leave the rest body and just change the 'div::before'

Comment: Yes. You could do that.

Comment: I think I managed to get it to work out for me. I really appreciate the help. It works way better than I expected (with the transition) when it goes very narrow it gets cut off on the sides, is there a number I can change so that it doesn't get cut even at really narrow (I don't know the pixel size of the narrow sized window)

Comment: Typically `767px` is considered as extra small for responsive styles. If you make it extremely narrow, then there will be some cutting off on sides, because it has to maintain the aspect ratio at all times. But, that would be minor annoyance. You will never get that narrow in real life for all practical purposes.

Comment: ok, good to know. Sorry to bother but last thing. Your code is making me rethink and recode my site to work better. However, I want to add content (text, buttons, etc) and a footer underneath that stays underneath and is responsive. Since the way you set up with absolute positioning, everything will end up on top or underneath the image

Comment: I don't get it. Could you create a sample fiddle and show where are you having a problem.

Comment: I've never used fiddle unfortunately. I got your example to work. and it works good, answered my question. Problem is I want to add content underneath the image. in a different div. (header image div which you provided, then a content div, then a footer div) but when I add a new div its put on top of the image

Comment: Basically, how would you add a div (or divs) that can have text content etc. to the code you provided? and stay underneath the header image as it resizes

Comment: I am beginning to suspect this could be an XY problem! Is this not about backgrounds? Is it about using image itself as content?

Comment: my site structure is header - which is a image that is responsive and takes up about a third of the screen no matter what size. (the code you provided answered that). then a content div with some text and buttons, then a footer div

Comment: Ahh.. ok.. gimme a couple of minutes.

Comment: I put your code to a div (headerdiv instead of body) but when I add another div underneath, it shows up on the image, I want it to stay underneath.

Comment: @user3550879: I think you were actually looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/pmtr5707/2/

Comment: that would do it, thank you. Happy holidays, you definitely made mine better